# What is the share of body energy that the brain consumes? Is 20% reliable?

Tags: brain, metabolism, energy

"20% of the energy at only 2% of the weight" is a frequently regurgitated factoid. More precisely, it should read: 20% of oxygen consumption.

The problem starts when one looks into the source experiment. The Wikipedia article on the [brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain) offers [Mink et al. 1981](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7282965/). Unfortunately, that paper merely summarizes the data of others and itself references the ancient [1957 paper by Kety](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/THE-GENERAL-METABOLISM-OF-THE-BRAIN-IN-VIVO-Kety/1bbbd22e2a1c654fe44cf01e76af4d2c0f3bd9f0), *The general metabolism of the brain in vivo (reference 50)*. Alas, Kety again only summarizes the data of yet others from the 40s and 50s (see table 1). So, we have a horrible case of *he said, she said*.

Does anybody know of a more recent and more reliable study that estimates the % of energy consumed by the brain?